# FreeBSD dhclient don't parse bootp-broadcast-always

Tags: freebsd, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

So, despite the fact that it's listen in the official documentation, the dhclient binary shipped with FreeBSD 12 does not support "bootp-broadcast-always". I'm trying to include this option in dhclient.conf file and get an error

```
/etc/dhclient.conf line 10: expecting a statement. 
bootp-broadcast-always;
^
```

No matter what I do, this option never gets parsed.
Also, I did a search in the official dhclient code located here: [ISC DHCLIENT](https://github.com/isc-projects/dhcp)
and there is such option. While, looking here [FreeBSD source tree](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/), there is no such option. What to do now? I really need this option! Maybe it's under another name?

Comment: If I grab the source from [the linked repository](https://github.com/isc-projects/dhcp) and search for `bootp-broadcast-always`, I don't see any matches.

Comment: Now go to link again. Press . (dot) on your keyboard. Then, on the left side select Search icon and type "bootp-broadcast-always". There you have it!

Comment: There are no matches in the [current source code in the repository](https://github.com/isc-projects/dhcp/search?q=bootp-broadcast-always&type=code). I don't know where you found documentation for that option, but it doesn't appear to be valid.

Comment: So, can you point a valid option that does the job? On my Linux Mint machine, this option works as expected. DISCOVER sends 0x8000(Broadcast) in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. Seems like there is no official way of forcing FreeBSD's client to request broadcast replies. So, I grabbed the one from ISC's GitHub and compiled it with patch. More info here - [netgate forum](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/141362/dhcp-client-unable-to-get-lease-from-cable-provider-solved)